# ¿SQL Server no es compatible con Window 11 single language?

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows11

Cuando intento descargar SQL Server me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí],

intento ver tutoriales y cambiar el idioma a español de españa pero Window 11  single language no permite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: SQL Server no es compatible con algunos idiomas, lo que no significa que no sea compatible con Windows 11 Single Language, sino que no es compatible con el idioma que instalaste. Con esa versión de Windows 11 no podras cambiar nunca el idioma a no ser que hagas un Downgrade a Windows 10 o adquieras la versión Pro de Windows 11.

Comment: Ya intentaste cambiando tu idioma a Español de España?, en versiones anteriores esa era la solución

Comment: En lo personal; uso SQL Server en máquina virtual usando Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; sin problemas al instalar. Hay cosas que no he podido habilitar (los JOBs de lo que he intentado usar) pero para los demás todo bien. Y no cargo mi compu mientras no lo uso.

Comment: El problema de Ubuntu es que no se le puede instalar el Reporting Services, los Jobs si se pueden pero, se instalan aparte.